# What is the template argument when reading a binary file to "unsigned char" vector

Tags: c++, vector, unsigned-char, istream-iterator

What's wrong with this code?

```
std::vector<unsigned char> newVector;
std::ifstream inFile(fullPath.c_str(), std::ios::in|std::ios::binary);
std::istreambuf_iterator iterator(inFile);
```

It gives me this:

```
missing template arguments before 'iterator'
```

And if I change it to this:

```
std::istreambuf_iterator<unsigned char> iterator(inFile);
```

It complains this:

```
invalid conversion from 'void*' to 
    'std::istreambuf_iterator<unsigned char>::streambuf_type
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ifstream` is a `basic_ifstream<char>`, not a `basic_ifstream<unsigned char>`. Therefore, you need to declare `iterator` as

```
std::istreambuf_iterator<char> iterator(inFile);
```

and it will work.

Comment: It doesn't matter if I'm reading a binary file to "unsigned char" vector?

Comment: @MikaelS.: No, it'll be fine. For example, you can do `newVector.insert(newVector.begin(), iterator, eos)` where `eos` is a default-initialized (end-of-stream) `istreambuf_iterator<char>`. All that matters there is that the vector element type (`unsigned char`) can be constructed from the iterator element type (`char`).